# Android Gradle Build - How to inject environment variable to properties file in assets directory?

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

This is nothing new to me, I have been doing this for months before Google released Gradle plugin for Android studio version 2.2.2 and it breaks the file lookup functionality.

**Use case:**

I am running gradle build within the Android studio as well as from the Jenkins. I need some build information to be passed to the build and then want it to be used by the code. These values include system information, build variant, build date and IP addresses for the associated build flavors.

**Before I switched to Gradle 2.2.2 from 2.1.3**

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.mergeResources.doLast {
        File propsFile = file("${buildDir}/intermediates/assets/${variant.dirName}/config.properties")
        println("Filtering resource file: " + propsFile)
        String content = propsFile.getText('UTF-8')
        println("File contents: " + content)
        content = content.replaceAll(/@build.date@/, buildDate)
                .replaceAll(/@build.mode@/, buildMode)
                .replaceAll(/@serverUri@/, serverUrl)
        propsFile.write(content, 'UTF-8')
    }
}
```

The above code looks up for the config.properties file in `intermediate/assets/${variant.dirName}` path. The file is then processed to replace the tokens marked with @..@ with the variables passed to replaceAll method.

**Now my problem is:**

The code was supposed to work with the newer Gradle plugin version 2.2.2. However, I observed that the newer build does not generate the asset folder in intermediate directory and so the above code fails to lookup the file and throws following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> /home/pawan/git/MyApplication/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/config.properties (No such file or directory)
```

It is apparent that the newer version has changed the way build operation works. Now question is, how should I go ahead from this point? How to achieve the intended functionality? Any workaround or fixes?

Comment: Have you tried to Invalidate Caches, Restart and Rebuild project ?

Comment: @ArsenSench Yes I did. This has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

May be [Build Environment](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html) will help for you. You can define environment variables in `gradle.properties` and assign it a default value. In you `build.gradle` file, just such environment variables. In you jenkins, use `gradlew` to assign your need value to variables, and the default value will be replaced.

For example, in your `gradle.properties`:

```
versCode=100
```

In  your `build.gradle`:

```
defaultConfig {
    // Other configs
    versionCode versCode as Integer
}
```

In  your jenkens build script :

```
./gradlew -PversCode=200 build
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem with the missing assets directory? I could any how obtain the values for the variables in build script but couldn't pass it to the files in assets directory. Btw, I don't use gradle wrapper. I use gradle (from installation).

Comment: It does not use asset directory. If want to use `gradle.properties`, need put it in directory with `gradlew`. If you use gradle, I think there are a directory called `gradle`, and there are gradle wrapper in it.